# Set two flags in Java regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex, unicode, case-sensitive

I need a matcher like this:

```java
Matcher kuchen = Pattern
        .compile("gibt es Kuchen in der K\u00FCche", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
        .matcher("");
```

and the problem is that it is not simple ASCII. I know that in this particular case I could use `[\u00FC\u00DC]` for the ü, but I need to be a bit more general (building the regex from other matcher groups). So according to [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE):

> By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being matched. Unicode-aware case-insensitive matching can be enabled by specifying the UNICODE_CASE flag in conjunction with this flag.

Can anybody tell me how to specify the two flags in conjunction?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try

```
Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE
```

it should solve the issue. Or-ing the bitmask you will get compound features.

Comment: Is it better practice to apply flags within the pattern itself or using the flag parameter within compile as shown in your answer?

Comment: Does including it in the pattern like in Joop's answer hold any disadvantages or is it purely preference? One potential pro for including it within the Pattern string is transferability. A colleague of mine reused one of my PCRE regexs without setting the case insensitive flag, which wouldn't have been a problem had I included it within the pattern itself.

Comment: @Deco It depends on your design and a situation might be different when you apply the pattern or use a flag, but the question is about flags.

Comment: @Deco It is neater to compile the flags into your pattern class, but using the regex paren question mark syntax gives you more control over where you want to start and/or stop the flags.

Answer (score 15):

Though more pure using parameters, same as `"(?iu)gibt es ..."` without parameters. `i` = case-insensitive, `u` = unicode.

Answer (score 11):

Use bitwise OR, like `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bitmask, so you use the bitwise OR operator `|`.